# How to move a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a `JDialog` which contains `JPanel` and other elements like `JTextField`. I want to move `JDialog` from one location to another after it is loaded on screen. When I try to use `jdialog.setLocation()`, I am not able to move `JDialog` and also all other components added to it becomes invisible.

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong with my approach?

Comment: Is it a modal dialog? I think it would be better to show us some code in order to help you.

Comment: You may wish to show us a small compilable runnable program that shows us your problem, an [sscce](http://sscce.org). It sounds like you're trying to do an animation of some sorts. Perhaps you need a Swing Timer in the mix.

Comment: @  Hovercraft Full Of Eels : Yes , I am trying to do animation

Comment: @ Dan : yes it is a modal dialog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding Gilbert's assertion that a dialog can't be moved after being set visible, please run this:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MovingDialog {
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(new JButton(new ShowMovingDialogAction()));
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("MovingDialog");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class ShowMovingDialogAction extends AbstractAction {
   private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

   public ShowMovingDialogAction() {
      super("Show Moving Dialog");
      panel.add(new JLabel("label"));
      panel.add(new JTextField("TextField", 10));
      panel.add(new JButton("Button"));
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JFrame owner = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor((Component) e
            .getSource());
      final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(owner, "Dialog",
            ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
      dialog.getContentPane().add(panel);
      dialog.pack();
      dialog.setLocation(0, 0);

      int delay = 20;
      new Timer(delay , new ActionListener() {
         int x = 0;
         int y = 0;
         Dimension scrn = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int maxX = scrn.width - dialog.getWidth();
            int maxY = scrn.height - dialog.getHeight();
            if (x < maxX  && y < maxY) {
               x++;
               y++;
               dialog.setLocation(x, y);
            } else {
               ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
            }
         }
      }).start();

      dialog.setVisible(true);

   }
}
```

Note that the animation Swing Timer *must* be started before calling setVisible(true). Perhaps that is what Gilbert was referring to.

Comment: I can't saw your code, then why OP asked this question twice, my respect +1

Answer (score 3):

If you try to do animation then you will have to initialize and start a new thread and do it there. The code inside the `run()` method of the thread should check if the dialog is visible and call `dialog.setLocation()` with modified values on each iteration.

Comment: can it be done with simulating mouse selection and dragging to a location? I am not sure if this a valid question

Comment: The question is valid and it may even be possible. However, I don't recommend you to do this as users will be totally scared and there will be competition between your code and the user for the mouse.

Comment: Dan: You should use a Swing Timer for this rather than a background thread. Yes it can be done with a background thread, but if you do it that way, you will need to take care to call all Swing methods on the Swing event thread. If you use a Swing Timer (which of course uses its own worker thread in the background), this issue is taken care of for you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : can you give me some idea about how that can be done?